# How can rewrite url using htaccess when add custom foulder name in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

I want to rewrite my URL using htaccss .I am working project in laravel 4 .I need to add following  names with url.but its showing error.

The names are like ,
admin,government,bus,school

My current site url is :http://localhost/myproject/

But i want to access url following like,

1)http://localhost/myproject/admin

2)http://localhost/myproject/government

3)http://localhost/myproject/bus

4)http://localhost/myproject/school

This is my current .httacess code,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can i add change to .htaccess file to access above urls.

Comment: To which URL do you want to rewrite those addresses?

Comment: i have 4 user type so i want rewrite from http://localhost/myproject/ to above urls

Comment: You need to be more specific. I understand that the user is going to visit localhost/myproject , and then you want to redirect the user to a sub-url like the 4 URL's described in the question. However, based on what should the web-server know which URL to redirect the user to? Random guessing?

Comment: i got this error:Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Comment: The url given below:'admin,government,bus,school'

Comment: Is `myproject` a real directory? Is above .htaccess in that directory?

Comment: yes it is real directory

Comment: i put htaccess file to inside directory